# SyntaxError: invalid syntax when opening a file

Tags: regex, python-2.7

```
import re

fhand = open('sum.txt','r')
number = re.findall('[0-9]'+, fhand)
print number
```

I am getting syntax error as

```
 number = re.findall('[0-9]'+, fhand)
                              ^
     SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Not sure what's going on. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1):

Read the file contents and declare the entire pattern inside a string literal.

Here is an example:

```
>>> import re
>>> fhand = open(r'D:\2\_1.txt','r')
>>> fhand
<open file 'D:\\2\\_1.txt', mode 'r' at 0x0282B230>
>>> number = re.findall('[0-9]+', fhand.read())
>>> print number
['1', '2', '3', '1', '0', '2', '0', '7', '0', '2', '2', '0', '3', '0', '5', '0', '3']
>>>
```